# Cin appears to be failing inside this loop. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm getting a compiler error when trying to build the code below and I don't quite understand what is failing and why.

It's pointing to line 45 (cin>>x[ctr]) with a "no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_istream&>'" message.

I've just started coding a few days ago and English is not my native language. Apologies if this question is below the community's paygrade. Hope you can point me in the right direction.

cpp.sh/34sm3

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//#include "_pause.h"


using namespace std;


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               NOTE
// This is your program entry point. Your main logic is placed
// inside this function. You may add your functions before this
// "main()", or after this "main()" provided you added reference
// before this "main()" function.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Write a program that can divide six non-zero integers (two integers per division) from the user and display the result to the user. 
//Create a function that will perform the division operation. Display only the non-decimal part of the quotient.




float quot (int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1/num2;
}


int main() 
{
    // ************************** TO DO **************************
    // Place your code logic after this comment line
    // ***********************************************************
    int x[6];
    cout<<"Enter 6 integers to divide: ";
    for(int ctr=0; ctr<6; ctr++)
    {
        cin>>[ctr];
        if(x[ctr]==0)
        {
            cout<<"Invalid number! Please enter a non-zero value: ";
            cin>>x[ctr];
        }
    }


    cout<<"The quotient of the first pair is: " << quot(x[0],x[1]) <<endl;
    cout<<"The quotient of the second pair is: " << quot(x[2],x[3]) <<endl;
    cout<<"The quotient of the third pair is: " << quot(x[4],x[5]) <<endl;


    system ("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Are cin statements inside for loops not allowed in C++?

Comment: `cin>>[ctr];` missing something ? like maybe an `x` ? `cin>>x[ctr];`

Comment: `cin` statements are allowed inside `for` loops.

Comment: It already has the x: ```cin>>x[ctr];```, the idea is to ask the user to replace any 0's with a non-zero value

Comment: @儚き戦士の翼 Look above your `if` statement within your loop. What do you see? Or rather, what *don't* you see? Possibly more to the point, look at what you posted for **us** to look at. That code is *clearly* missing the array name.

Comment: Thank you all, I did not see line 41. I'll be more careful in the future

Answer (score 1):

i guess you need to replace `cin>>[ctr]` with `cin>>x[ctr]`.....this might fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function `quot` should be written like

```
float quot (int num1, int num2)
{
    return static_cast<float>( num1 ) / num2;
}
```

Otherwise the return type float does not make a great sense because in this expression `num1 / num2` there is used the integer arithmetic.

It is obvious that in this statement

```
cin>>[ctr];
```

there is a typo. You forgot to specify the array name `x`

```
cin >> x[ctr];
```

Also it will be better to subsritute this if statement

```
    if(x[ctr]==0)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid number! Please enter a non-zero value: ";
        cin>>x[ctr];
    }
```

for a while statement like

```
    while ( x[ctr] == 0 )
    {
        cout<<"Invalid number! Please enter a non-zero value: ";
        cin>>x[ctr];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### That's all you had to do.

Just change `cin>>[ctr]` to `cin>>x[ctr]` 
It's on line **41**. You need to specify the array name, `x` before the index `[ctr]`
Here's your code.

I recommend you to use a debugger to figure out such small human-made-errors yourself.
Also, read your code and try to visualize its flow before asking for solutions.

```
int main() 
{
    // ************************** TO DO **************************
    // Place your code logic after this comment line
    // ***********************************************************
    int x[6];
    cout<<"Enter 6 integers to divide: ";
    for(int ctr=0; ctr<6; ctr++)
    {
        cin>>x[ctr];
        if(x[ctr]==0)
        {
            cout<<"Invalid number! Please enter a non-zero value: ";
            cin>>x[ctr];
        }
    }


    cout<<"The quotient of the first pair is: " << quot(x[0],x[1]) <<endl;
    cout<<"The quotient of the second pair is: " << quot(x[2],x[3]) <<endl;
    cout<<"The quotient of the third pair is: " << quot(x[4],x[5]) <<endl;


    system ("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```